# Framework and Database Suggestions for a Large Scale Web Application

Tags: mongodb, angular, firebase, vue.js, single-page-application

I'm looking at building a (hopefully) large scale web application. The application will manage many users with lots of data, therefore a large database.

My issue is that I cannot decide which framework, or database software I should use.

I'm torn between using Angular2 or Vue.js 2.0, and Firebase or MongoDB.

Could somebody please provide some guidance or scale-ability, use on large scale apps etc.. on the above.

Any guidance will be much appreciated.

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Did you already work with the technologies you hesitate to use ?

Comment: I've worked with Vue.js and Angular2 before, I've not used MongoDB or Firebase

Comment: Angular2 is baked by google and was made for bigger apps than Vue (imho). Concerning the database, if you have a lot of relations I would stick with something more classic like Postgre or Mysql. Firebase "scale" well because you dont have to do anything but then you will have to pay. There is no a black or white answer.

Comment: Thanks Fabien, I might go with Angular2 and a standard MySQL database then!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of you are still deciting on which NoSQL database to choose: This survey could be of much help: https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=12289975